# How to start css animation on click and run the animation reversed on second click?

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to create an animated hamburger menu. I found out about CSS animations and I decided to use that.

The setup of the menu is very easy: I have a background color and the two divs that make up the hamburger menu.

I have created a square div, and positioned that on the top right corner of my menu. My goal for now is that the background fades in when I click on this button. The button is now green, but that’s temporarily. I will animate the rest of the menu when I now how to start an animation on click.

I’ve already tried a lot to solve this, but it just doesn’t work. I hope you can help me!

The below code is the code I now have. I did not add the code that’s not so relevant to this question.

The menu should also close when I click the button again, so the animations should run reversed. How can I best do this?

Thanks! Ralph

index.html

```html
</div>
    <div class="dsgn-header">
        <div class="dsgn-header-menu-opened">
            <div class="dsgn-header-menu-opened-background"></div>
            <div class="dsgn-header-menu-opened-menuitems"></div>
        </div>

    <div class="dsgn-header-logo">
        <p class="dsgn-header-title">Site title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dsgn-header-menu-mobile">
        <div class="dsgn-header-rectangle-up"></div>
        <div class="dsgn-header-rectangle-down"></div>
    <div class="dsgn-header-button" onclick="ani()" ></div>
</div>
```

header.css

```css
.dsgn-header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 88px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  background-color: white;
}



/* Logo */

@media (max-width: 350px) {
  .dsgn-header-logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 16px;
    top: 27px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 351px) {
  .dsgn-header-logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 28px;
    top: 27px;
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 500px;
  }
}

.dsgn-header-title {
  color: #FF0000;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}


/* Menu animation */

.dsgn-header-rectangle-up {
  position:absolute;
  width:40px;
  height:1px;
  background:grey;
  right:28px;
  top:40px;
  -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name: dsgn-header-rectangle-up;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.dsgn-header-rectangle-down {
  position:absolute;
  width:40px;
  height:1px;
  background:grey;
  right:28px;
  top:54px;
  -webkit-animation-name: dsgn-header-rectangle-down; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name: dsgn-header-rectangle-down;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
  0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
  100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* Let op de ease in ease out en de animation iteration */


/* Menu opened */

.dsgn-header-menu-opened-background-active {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
background-color: black;
 -webkit-animation-name: menu-background; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name: menu-background;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}


/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes menu-background {
  0%   {
opacity: 0;
}
  100%   {
opacity: 1;
}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes menu-background {
  0%   {
opacity: 0;
}
  100%   {
opacity: 1;
}
}



.dsgn-header-menu-opened-menuitems {
  position: absolute;
  left: 45px;
  top: 150px;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.dsgn-header-button {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
width: 88px;
height: 88px;
background-color: green;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('#dsgn-header-button').onClick(function(){
    $('#dsgn-header-menu-opened-background').addClass('.dsgn-header-menu-opened-background-active');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to make this reversible animation, I suggest you to use `transition` instead of `keyframes`, since when you start the `animation`, there's no way to keep track the current state and the target state, so if you click the button while the animation is unfinished, it'll jump directly to the last frame and play reverse.

But still, here's the solution:

```js
const demo = document.querySelector('.demo');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

let reverse = false;

button.addEventListener('click', onClickPlay);

function onClickPlay(){
  // Save the animation state
  let animation = demo.style.animation;
  
  // Clear the animation
  demo.style.animation = 'none';
  
  // You need to call this at next draw call to make the animation take effects
  setTimeout(()=>{
    // Restore the animation
    demo.style.animation = animation;
    // Make the animation running
    demo.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
    // Set the animation direction by current state
    demo.style.animationDirection = reverse ? 'reverse' : 'normal';
    // Flip the state
    reverse = !reverse;
    button.innerText = reverse ? 'Reverse' : 'Forward';
  }, 0);
}
```

```css
@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
    background-color: red;
  }
  
  100% {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

.demo {
  /* Make the animation paused at the beginning */
  animation: anim 1s paused both;
  width: 0px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button>Forward</button>
<div class="demo"><div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. There is only one thing that's not working. I removed the <button> and replaced that with a div .buttondemo. Then I changed the JS to make it work. This worked. After that I made the demo fullheight and width. I styled the buttondemo class, I made it square and positioned it in the upper right corner with position: absolute. The problem now is that the .demo is not fullwidth anymore, it starts at the left border of the button. When I place the button at the upper left corner, the .demo becomes fullwidth again. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Well, don't really know what is going on there. But you're not supposed to use this code directly; it's just the concept. Perhaps you can show me the code via CodePen or jsfiddle so I can help :/

Comment: Hi! I put it into this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ralphsmit/gs97x6n5/10/. Please try changing the right: 0px; to left: 0px; for the class .buttondemo. Then you will see what I mean. Thanks for taking the time to help me?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? https://jsfiddle.net/wheatup/ev1t0wx4/2/

If it's that kind of simple animation, you can achieve it with `transition`, it's much easier and looks better: https://jsfiddle.net/wheatup/j8msh17p/4/

Comment: That’s indeed what I want. I also want two small rectangles to rotate into a cross, for the hamburger menu. I think I can do that myself! Thanks for your help! What did you do to fix the issue I had?

Comment: Basically because you set `position: absolute` and `right: 0` for `buttondemo` but forgot to set them for `demo` as well since these two elements are independent.

Comment: O now I understand! Thanks for your help